# Error : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to read data from sql server via EF core in desktop application.
I can get connection string With below code  :

```
using (ModelsContext db = new ModelsContext())
                {
                    var x = db.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
                    //db.Database.Connection.Close();
                }
```

But when I try to read table's data get me error that is :

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is
> not trusted.)

My model class :

```
 internal class ModelsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PumpsStatu>  Status { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Drive> Drives { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(@"data source=.;initial catalog=SpmsTwoSuctionOneThrust;user id=SPMS-User;password=*********;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            
        }
    }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#high-impact-changes) for EF Core 7:

> This is a severe breaking change in the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package
> `SqlClient` connection strings use Encrypt=True by default.

Options to mitigate:

> There are three ways to proceed:
>
> - Install a valid certificate on the server. Note that this is an involved process and requires obtaining a certificate and ensuring it is signed by an authority trusted by the client.
> - If the server has a certificate, but it is not trusted by the client, then `TrustServerCertificate=Tru`e to allow bypassing the normal trust mechanism.
> - Explicitly add `Encrypt=False` to the connection string.

2nd and 3rd options are ok to use for local development environments.

Comment: I add Encrypt=False to end of connection string but get error  :  Invalid object name 'Drives'.   My code is : db.Drives.ToList();

Comment: @hmahdavi I would argue that this is a completely different question. Have you migrated the database?

Comment: Have you migrated the database? No.  My database is ready and full of data

Comment: @hmahdavi again - this is completely separate question which will require a [mre]. It seems that you have some mismatch between how you have set up the context and table names.

Comment: I use scaffolding to generate Models and fixed. Thank you